# WWII documentary series with end credits that used a diorama

Tags: television

I remember a series about World War II where the end credits were shown over a camera that panned over a diorama that show the progress of the war that started with normal scenes that slowly transitioned by the end of the credits to bombed out cities. I thought it might be the classic BBC *The World at War*, but the episodes I've seen on Youtube don't have the diorama.

Comment: The World at War does show a top-down view of a moving diorama that sounds like what you are describing.  https://youtu.be/m0mrOeJwXBI

Comment: At the end of The World at War, episode freezes the last frame of the historical footage they are using and shows the credits over it.The show I'm thinking of had a long miniature country side and towns like one might build for a train set that showed the passage of time as they panned front to back. Thank you I love that music and Lawrence Olivier's voice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be thinking of People's Century https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=People%27s+Century

Comment: I think you can see how I might confuse it with The World at War. Both these series were excellent. Thank You